# How to reference .cpp files without including them into the solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, lua, luabind, c++

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
}

#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>
#include<iostream>
int main(){
   lua_State*pL=lua_open();

   luabind::open(pL);

   lua_close(pL);
   return 0;
}
```

But I don't have a .lib of `luabind`, so I use the source with the .h/.cpp files.
The way I do it is by adding the directories to include, but I get a link error.
The only way I can compile is by adding the .cpp files as existing elements, but the solution tree gets messy with the additional files. 
Can somebody tell me if there's a way to add the directory of the additional .cpp files in the solution's properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile the lua cpp files into a static library. Add the directory where you put those under "linker | input | additional library directories".

Comment: So the only way its to compile a static library or add the cpp files into the solution

Comment: @user595560: I'm not sure it's the *only* way, but I'm pretty sure it is the easiest/cleanest way.

Comment: It's definitely not the only way (It is the cleanest): You could always `#include` them into a file already in your project =P.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the linker where to find the functions referenced by the .h files (the .lib file, typically).